# Incorrect String Length Using Pointer

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program that displays the string length of an entered string with a pointer to aforementioned string. When I input a string without spaces, the length is correct. When I enter a string with spaces, the length is incorrect. Please describe my mistake and recommend ways to fix it.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int l,n;
    char s[n], *p=s;
    *p = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
    n = sizeof(*p);
    if (p==NULL)
    printf("Unable to allocate memory");

    printf("Input a string: ");
    scanf("%s", p);
    l = strlen(p);
    printf("\nLength of given string: %d\n", l);
}
```

Input:

> Input a string: June 27

Output:

> Length of given string: 4

Comment: You allocated `p` with a length of `5`. You're overflowing your buffer.

Comment: You allocated enough space for four characters and a null byte.  You entered seven characters.  Things are not going to work well.

Comment: `char s[n];`, `*p = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);` Each of those should be generating at least a warning, which you shouldn't ignore. Either that, or what you posted is not the real code.

Comment: `scanf("%s"...` reads to the first whitespace, and you are responsible for providing the memory, so it's a good thing you put a space after "June".

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the obvious memory allocation shortcomings mentioned in the comments, "%s" used with scanf will read up to the first whitespace. If you want to read complete lines (up to newline), consider using fgets instead.

Answer (score 0):

**The program has the following defects:**

1. The variable `n` is uninitialized before its usage in `char s[n]`.
2. You're trying to read the whole line by `scanf()` which only reads to the next whitespace.
3. Allocated memory of `5` length, which is an overflow and tends to Undefined Behavior.
4. The `(char *)` is not explicitly defined during memory allocation.

---

**Code redefined:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 100

int main(void) {
    char *s;

    s = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX); // allocating memory correctly

    if (s == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(s, MAX, stdin); // reading the entire line

    size_t len = 0;

    while (s[len++]); // alternative of strlen()

    printf("String length is: %d\n", len);

    return 0;
}
```

**A sample output:**

```
$ gcc -o prog prog.c; ./prog
Enter a string: Hello world, how are you today?
String length is: 33
```

Comment: In C it's frowned upon to cast the `void*` result of `malloc()`. Just let the compiler do the right thing.

Comment: Why did you invent your own `strlen()`?

Comment: @thebusybee I invented own `strlen()` to reduce the program size by not adding the entire header file just for a simple function. If the thing could be done in simple, then let it be done.

Comment: The size of a header file says nothing about the growth of the resulting binary. I can add zillions of bytes of header files without adding any byte to the executable. Did you compare your DIY solution with the provided `strlen()` to back up your claim?